# Download Copernicus Marine variables with Package RCMEMS - Error code 9

Tags: r, error, download, copernicus, github

I'm using the source code RCMEMS (https://github.com/markpayneatwork/RCMEMS) to download several marines variables and I have a error despite having respect syntax package.

To biginning, according to my python terminal I use *Python 3.6.0* and *motuclient-python v1.8.6*:

```
F:\PNB_ENTROPIE>python --version
```

> Python 3.6.0

```
F:\PNB_ENTROPIE>python -m motuclient --version
```

> motuclient-python v1.8.6

For example, I tried to download SST variable (https://resources.marine.copernicus.eu/?option=com_csw&view=details&product_id=SST_GLO_SST_L3S_NRT_OBSERVATIONS_010_010) with VScode and R language :

```
devtools::install_github("markpayneatwork/RCMEMS", force = TRUE)

cfg_manuel <- RCMEMS::CMEMS.config(
                    motu = "http://nrt.cmems-du.eu/motu-web/Motu",
                    python = "C:/Users/romai/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe",
                    script = "C:/Users/romai/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/motuclient-script.py",
                    user = "rfernandez1",
                    auth.mode = "basic",
                    pwd = "XXXXXXX",
                    service.id = "SST_GLO_SST_L3S_NRT_OBSERVATIONS_010_010-TDS",
                    product.id = "IFREMER-GLOB-SST-L3-NRT-OBS_FULL_TIME_SERIE",
                    longitude.min = "10",
                    longitude.max = "155",
                    latitude.min = "-55 ",
                    latitude.max = "31",
                    date.min = "2020-12-16",
                    date.max = "2020-12-31",
                    variable = "sea_surface_temperature", 
                    out.dir = "F:/PNB_ENTROPIE/Variables",
                    out.name = "Test_RCMEMS"
)
```

When I want download my variable stocked in `cfg_manuel`  object :

```
RCMEMS::CMEMS.download(cfg_manuel)
```

I have this output:

> ```
> 2021-01-19 15:00:32.157 [ INFO] Asynchronous mode set
> 2021-01-19 15:00:32.160 [ INFO] Requesting file to download (this can take a while)...
> 2021-01-19 15:00:34.557 [ERROR] Execution failed: junk after document element: line 30, column 1
> 2021-01-19 15:00:34.558 [ INFO]  . code  9:
> Error in (function (x, out.dir = NULL, out.name = NULL, date.min = NULL,  :
>   Error in running CMEMS download command.
> ```

What is this error and where does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, my option was incorrect : `auth.mode = "cas"`